# Why is the following "in" operator not finding the strings inside this array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that checks if the key belongs to the "count" category:

```
isCountKey (key) {
  const countKeys = [
    'buildingCount',
    'panoramaCount'
  ] // TODO find a better way to check for count keys
  console.log(key)
  console.log(key in countKeys)
  return key in countKeys
}
```

`console.log` however, always returns `false`, even when key is `buildingCount` and `panoramaCount`:

```
name
List.vue?2658:38 false
List.vue?2658:42 number
List.vue?2658:38 false
List.vue?2658:42 buildingCount
List.vue?2658:38 false
List.vue?2658:42 panoramaCount
List.vue?2658:38 false
```

Why is this?

Comment: You have an array which as numeric indexes... use a object.. `countKeys = {[
    'buildingCount':true,
    'panoramaCount':true
  }`

Comment: because keys here are 0 and 1

Comment: or use `countKeys .indexOf(key) != -1`

Comment: Did you read the description of the `in` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` tests to see if a property with the same **name** as the string exists, not a property with the same **value**. Test with `"length"` or `"0"` and it would work.

Use [the `indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to search an array for a matching value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` instead

```
// If element is not in array, indexOf returns -1, not returning -1 means the key is in the array

var isKeyInArray = (countKeys.indexOf(key) != -1); 
console.log(isKeyInArray)
```